# É possível alterar uma palavra de uma string por outra na base de dados através de php?

Tags: php, mysql, string

Eu tenho estado a trabalhar num método que vai buscar todas as datas que contenham "2014" e substituir esse valor por "2016" sem alterar o resto da data. Já consegui retornar todas as colunas que contenham "2014" mas não sei como alterar só esse valor em todas as strings. Agradeço qualquer sugestão.

O código que executei foi o seguinte:

```
        <?php
                $query = "SELECT * ";
                $query .= "FROM voo ";

                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if(!$result) {
                    die ("Database query failed.");
                }

            //while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
                //  if (strpos($result,'2014') !== false) {
                        $query = "UPDATE voo SET DataPartida = DATE_ADD(DataPartida, ";
                        $query .= "INTERVAL 2 YEAR) WHERE year(DataPartida) = '2014'";
                        var_dump($row);
                    //}
                    echo "<hr />";
                //}
        ?>
```

Exemplo: "2014-01-02 18:00:00" Pretende-se que fique "2016-01-02 18:00:00"

Comment: Poderias fazer alguma coisa com `regex`.

Comment: Procurei por esse método  (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL), e era mesmo algo do género que estava a procura, mas php.net diz que vai deixar de ser compitavel com os browsers: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @angelfmf a função não está obsoleta, o que está obsoleto é o modificador `e`. "O modificador `/e` está obsoleto. Use preg_replace_callback() como alternativa. Veja a documentação `PREG_REPLACE_EVAL` para adicionais informações sobre riscos de segurança." E não tem o porque os browser não suportarem, porque a função roda no servidor e não no browser.

Comment: @angelfmf O campo no banco de dados é de que tipo? De longe, regex é a pior opção nesse caso.

Comment: se os dados estão num formato adequado para o tipo datetime, modifique a coluna para o tipo datetime, então poderá aplicar uma única query para atualizar os dados. Não tem necessidade de usar php... mas se quer fazer a query pelo php também não tem problema. Mas é completamente desnecessário fazer loop em todos os registros e fazer as substituições com php.

Comment: A Coluna já é do tipo datetime, verifiquei na base de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo formato do campo parece ser do tipo data(datetime, timestamp etc), nesse caso use as funções de manipulação de datas como [date_add()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) que adiciona um período da data.

Exemplo

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

Seu código deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
update voo set data = date_add(data, interval 2 year) where year(data) = '2014'
```

[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ab80/1)

```
$query = "UPDATE voo SET
             DataPartida = DATE_ADD(DataPartida,INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
          WHERE year(DataPartida) = '2014'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if(!$result) {
   die(mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pela óptima sugestão, tentei seguir o seu exemplo mas não tive sucesso. Já estive imenso tempo de volta do código e tentei fazer as alterações necessárias. Só comecei o PHP há umas semanas, por isso ainda é complicado achar solução para tudo.

Comment: @angelfmf, execute o Update direto no mysqli_query não precisa do while como explicou o Daniel omine

Comment: Já executei sem o loop mas continua a não haver alteração

Comment: @Angelfmf, na sua atualização faltou chamar o mysqli_query($connection, $query)

Comment: Desculpe, não consigo descobrir como chamar o mysqli_query, pensei que já estivesse chamado em cima,  mas dá através de $result certo, uma vez que está definido com esse valor. Pode só mostrar me onde chamar? Obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: Obrigado, já consegui executar o código com sucesso, foi muito prestável. Estava a chamar o mysqli_query antes queries, daí não executar